# Are there any games that have an ecological setting?

Tags: game-recommendation, campaign-settings

In [Tales from the Wood](http://www.thefreerpgblog.com/2009/07/go-natural-in-tales-from-wood-simon.html) you play woodland animals, seeing struggles against humans from an animal perspective. I was wondering if there were any games that used ecological/climate change as part of the setting?

It doesn't have to be mass extinctions or apocalypse but perhaps an oncoming/departing ice age.

[edit] Although Wraith has answered the question, if anyone knows of any additional settings, I'd be very interested to read it!

Comment: There's also Bunnies and Burrows; I didn't mention it in my answer because it seemed similar to the game that you mentioned above.  In addition, I'm not sure if these sources would be regarded as appropriate, but there are also scholastic papers on RPGs used for this purpose.  http://www.jstor.org/stable/4446750 has one (not free) that apparently describes a role-playing game that can be used by teachers to teach ecology.  http://www.ecologyandsociety.org/vol16/iss3/art27/main.html describes the use of the RUPES RPG in studies.  Interesting, but I'm not sure if they are salient.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Though [Blue Planet](http://www.redbrick-limited.com/cms/index.php?categoryid=20) is set on another planet, it was created along an environmentalist theme, with a exhaustively researched and scientifically accurate setting.  It is set 200 years from now, when the human race has irreparably damaged the ecology of the Earth.  A myriad of plant and animal species have gone extinct, and a 75-year worldwide famine has just ended.

Many years before the fall of Earth civilization as it existed, a mysterious artificial wormhole was discovered beyond the edge of the solar system. Expeditions, and eventually a colonization mission were sent to the star system at the other end of the wormhole.  The second planet of the system, dubbed Lambda Serpentis, was covered with a single vast ocean and was suitable for human life.  This planet was named Poseidon.

After Earth was restored (other than ecologically), attempts were made to contact the colonists.  In the interim, they had 'gone native', and the game explores the conflicts between the colonists, earth cultures, and the native cultures in a sort of Avatar on a water-covered world instead of a jungle-filled world.

It is a critically acclaimed setting, if not commercially popular.  The game has gone through two versions (three if you include the obligatory GURPS conversion) and three publishers, and is now with Red Brick Publishing.

For more information, see the [Red Brick](http://www.redbrick-limited.com/cms/index.php?categoryid=67&book_id=47) site or the [introduction by the original publishers](http://www.biohazardgames.com/bp.html).

Comment: RedBrick is hoping to get a 3rd edition out around GenCon 2012.

Comment: There is a GURPS version as well... http://sjgames.com/gurps/books/blueplanet/ ... but its out of print.

Comment: That's what obligatory GURPS conversion referred to. :)  Though out of print, it's still available for a relatively inexpensive price if you look around, i.e. at Amazon - http://www.amazon.com/GURPS-Blue-Planet-William-Stoddard/dp/1556345887

Answer (score 1):

The D&D Basic setting Mystara reached it's current geography following the explosion of a nuclear space ship.  It shifted the axis of the planet which sent the ancestral home of the elves into the polar region and they had to move.  They literally became environmental refugees, and when they settled again it was at the chagrin of their host country.  This is also often claimed to be the source of the monstrous humans, orcs, goblins and the like as descendants of mutated halflings and elves and whatnot.  (There are also some mages that harness the radiation as a power source instead of the typical magical source.)

Shadowrun has a strong theme of environmental misconduct.  For that matter, really any post-apocalyptic RPG will have ecological disaster as a theme.

There's also the myriad video games and movies that feature decimated worlds that can be adapted pretty easily into something like GURPS;  Water World 20 years later, or Fallout 3 Supers edition.

Answer (score 0):

Fading Suns, is...sort of.  The science is a bit soft, but it's like Dune.  I suppose it's really more of a game where ecology matters (shouldn't it always matter? But I can't recall a GM who had characters deal with, say, *rain* or any other natural hindrance.)